# localhost not accessible from a device that is connected to the same network over wifi

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, wireless-router, lamp

Strictly a no-vice question.

Consider my computer (holding apache webserver) as Comp-A,

Comp-A is connected to the router (at 192.168.1.1) through a switch and has ip-address of 192.168.1.41. All these connections are wired.

I have my Android Mobile, say Comp-B connected to the same router over wifi.

When I access as below from Comp-B, I could not find the page.

```
http://192.168.1.41:80
```

(that 80 was because I configured apache to work on port 80)

but I am able to access 192.168.1.41 from a computer thats connected to the router over wired connection, I get the access

What All I have tried:

- editing the httpd.conf to allow all request.
- made my ip static over the network
- even used dsniff to arpspoof Comp-A to be the router at 192.168.1.1 and when I try accessing 192.168.1.1 from Comp-B, I am still not getting the access.

What I actually feel:

- I feel that router separates the wired and wireless by keeping them in a different network (this is completely an imagination. I have no idea whats happening in router). If this is whats happening, how am I suppose to have them linked? with common dhcp?

Router is D-Link dsl 2750-U

Comment: What's the IP and mask of Comp-A and Comp-B? Can they ping each other?  What's the error message when trying to browse that web page?

Comment: We arp -scan 'ned and found out that the Comp-B's ip-address was not on the list. we had a Comp-C connected over wifi to the same router and figured out that the Comp-B(android) was on the list. both having same subnet mask 255.255.255.0. In short, Comp-A(wired to router) behaves like a different network and Comp-B and Comp-C (wireless to router) behaves differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (if not all) Wireless enabled routers/hotspots have an option designed to isolate users both on wireless and wired.

This generally means that if you are on the wireless nothing else except the gateway and the internet are accessible for you.

Check your configuration and look for "Isolate Wireless clients" or similar.

Another option is that the wireless is in a different VLAN and is not allowed to communicate with the wired interfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zeridon. Its was really frustrating that a single check box was the cause of this problem and it was "Enable Multi-AP Isolation". Thank you so much!